# python - paho.mqtt.client doesn't work anymore

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto

Some weeks ago I wrote a python script to send simple messages to an mosquitto broker.
I installed python 2.7.13 and paho.mqtt package. The server ran over my laptop, as the client.

Now, I have installed a mosquitto server on a raspberry and I'm trying to run the same script (WITHOUT CHANGE):

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

something something something

mqttClient = mqtt.Client()
mqttClient.connect(host = raspberry_MQTT_ip, port=1883)
mqttClient.publish("topic/state",jsonData)
```

but in console now appears:

```
"No module named paho.mqtt.client"
```

I've also tried to reinstall paho.mqtt package but obviosly console says:

```
"Requirement already satisfied: paho-mqtt in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages"
```

so... any hint?

Comment: Debug the problem step by step: `python --version`; `ls /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py`; `python -c "import paho"`; `python -c "import paho.mqtt"`; `python -c "import paho.mqtt.client"`

Comment: python version is 2.7.13. 
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py exists.
python -c "import paho" return "no module named paho".
Obviously the subsequents give same error

Comment: `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`

Comment: ['', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',

Comment: '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/andrea/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages',

Comment: '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Comment: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages is not in sys.path, hence no import. Either add /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages to sys.path or install paho to a directory in sys.path.

Comment: excuse me, what you means for sys.path

Comment: [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.path) is a Python variable in module `sys`. It's used by Python to find where to import modules from. You can change sys.path in you scripts or you can set PYTHONPATH environment variable (don't forget to export it) in your shell. Or you can install paho into a directory that Python already known (one of those listed above).

Comment: sorry but I don't understand. my fault surely. 
I would install paho in th right directory but to install paho I have just done pip install paho-mqtt, without any option and in the root directory.

Comment: Not necessary your fault. It seems pip installs into correct location, but for some reason /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages is not in sys.path. Either append it in your script (before import) or set PYTHONPATH env var before the script.

Comment: I've solved appending manually the path. thank you phd